# Digital Ocean Hostin Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean

this is my first time deploying a rails application and I have no idea how to do it.
I am with Digital Ocean, I have the $5 Droplet, and I must say they are great so far, also provide great documentation. I have been reading this, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-1-click-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-10-with-digitalocean
and there is already an application on my server.

So my question is, since my application runs fine locally on production mode, can I just ssh in my droplet, and replace the existing app, with mine? with just a `git clone .....` ?
Without using capistrano ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

HOWEVER, I would suggest using capistrano. It allows you to do things far quicker than if you were to do it yourself.

IE. When you deploy, you can automatically migrate your database. Capistrano also keeps backups of the last couple deploys, which would allow you to revert everything if something that you didn't notice during your tests went wrong.

On a side note, it is not that hard to setup. It would also allow you to deploy to multiple machines and environments easily.

Comment: Also, another question.. I don't know if its silly or not, I guess I will not need to run the rails server in production mode right? I mean Nginx will be already serving pages ?

Comment: If it is your production server, run in production mode. Nginx will not serve your pages. It can serve your assets though, if configured to do so.

Comment: I haven't reached that point yet, but do you just run "rails s -e production &" in the background? and then exit the ssh connection? I am probably over simplifying stuff

Comment: While that *should* work to start the rails server, do you really want to have to do that every time you want to start the server? When you could just `cap production deploy`?

Comment: nginx is the web server (it will serve the raw HTTP requests) but you need an application server for serving your Rails application (like [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com), [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org), [puma](http://puma.io)). `rails server` works for local development, but it's not intended for production use. I would recommend Passenger for getting started.